# TikZ matrix of pics

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a picture showing a matrix of small pictures drawn as a `\pic`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz,xstring}

\tikzset{FilteredSphere/.pic={
        \begin{scope}[every node/.append style={inner sep=1pt, outer sep=2pt}, x=2mm, y=2mm]
            %\fill[white] (0,0) circle (2);
            %       \begin{scope}[gray]
                %           \draw[dashed] (2,0) arc (0:180:2 and 0.6);
                %           \draw (0,0) circle (2) ;
                %           \draw (-2,0) arc (180:360:2 and 0.6);
                %       \end{scope}
            \begin{scope}[opacity=.5]
                \IfSubStr{#1}{f}{
                    \begin{scope}
                        \clip (0,2) arc (90:-90:2) arc (-90:90:.6 and 2);
                        \shade[ball color=red!70] (0,0) circle[radius=2];
                    \end{scope}
                    \begin{scope}
                        \clip (0,2) arc (90:-90:2) arc (-90:90:1.2 and 2);
                        \shade[ball color=red!70] (0,0) circle[radius=2];
                    \end{scope}
                }{}
                \IfSubStr{#1}{g}{
                    \begin{scope}
                        \clip (0,2) arc (90:-90:-2 and 2) arc (-90:90:.6 and 2);
                        \shade[ball color=blue!60] (0,0) circle[radius=2];
                    \end{scope}
                    \begin{scope}
                        \clip (0,2) arc (90:-90:-2 and 2) arc (-90:90:-1.3 and 2);
                        \shade[ball color=blue!60] (0,0) circle[radius=2];
                    \end{scope}
                }{}
                \IfSubStr{#1}{h}{
                    \begin{scope}
                        \clip (0,2) arc (90:-90:-1.2 and 2) arc (-90:90:1.2 and 2);
                        \shade[ball color=green!70] (0,0) circle[radius=2];
                    \end{scope}
                }{}
            \end{scope}
            \begin{scope}[thick]
                \IfSubStr{#1}{a}{\draw[red] (0,2) arc (90:-90:-1.3 and 2) node[below left, pos=.9] {\IfSubStr{#1}{A}{$a$}{}};}{}
                \IfSubStr{#1}{b}{\draw[blue] (0,2) arc (90:-90:1.2 and 2) node[below right, pos=.9] {\IfSubStr{#1}{B}{$b$}{}};}{}
                \IfSubStr{#1}{c}{
                    \IfSubStr{#1}{h}{
                        \draw[Aqua, densely dotted] (0,2) arc (90:270:-0.6 and 2) node[left=-2pt, midway] {\IfSubStr{#1}{C}{$c$}{}};
                    }{
                        \draw[Aqua] (0,2) arc (90:270:-0.6 and 2) node[left=-2pt, midway] {\IfSubStr{#1}{C}{$c$}{}};
                    }
                }{}
            \end{scope}
            \IfSubStr{#1}{x}{\fill (0,2) circle (0.15);}{}
            \IfSubStr{#1}{y}{\fill (0,-2) circle (0.15);}{}
            \path
            (0,2) arc (90:-90:2) node[text=red, pos=.4, above right] {\IfSubStr{#1}{F}{$f$}{}}
            (0,2) arc (90:-90:-2 and 2) node[text=blue!50!black, pos=.6,, below left]  {\IfSubStr{#1}{G}{$g$}{}}
            (-1.9, .65) node[text=green!50!black] {\IfSubStr{#1}{H}{$h$}{}}
            (0,2) node[left]{\IfSubStr{#1}{X}{$x$}{}}
            (0,-2) node[left]{\IfSubStr{#1}{X}{$y$}{}};
        \end{scope}
}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \matrix [column sep=0.5em, row sep=0.45em, cells={draw}] {
            \pic {FilteredSphere={xya}}; &
            \pic {FilteredSphere={xyabhH}};  &
            \pic {FilteredSphere={xyabchg}};  &
            \pic {FilteredSphere={xyabcfgh}};
            \\
            \pic {FilteredSphere={xya}};  &
            \pic {FilteredSphere={xyab}};    &
            \pic {FilteredSphere={xyabcgG}};    &
            \pic {FilteredSphere={xyabcfg}};   &
            \\
            \pic {FilteredSphere={xy}};   &
            \pic {FilteredSphere={xyb}};   &
            \pic {FilteredSphere={xybc}};   &
            \pic {FilteredSphere={xybcfF}};
            \\
            \pic {FilteredSphere={xyXY}};   &
            \pic {FilteredSphere={xy}};  &
            \pic {FilteredSphere={xycC}};   &
            \pic {FilteredSphere={xyc}}; \\
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Now, I was asked to draw horizontal and vertical rules between rows and columns of this matrix. Apparently, `\pic`s are no nodes, and I cannot name them and refer to their anchors. What should I do?

I don't want to build a `matrix` of `tikzpictures`, because I want to retain the ability to externalize the picture as a whole, if possible. Plus, then I have to mess around with the alignment.

Comment: `pics` can be place on `node` or `coordinate` like this:
`\coordinate (P) at (1,1); \pic at (P);` with this you can use a loop to place all of them

Comment: To continue @anis idea, look up fit in the manual for an outer boarder.

Comment: What do you mean by border of the matrix? The matrix itself is a node (and has also a shape), so you can just add `draw` to the option of the matrix.

Comment: If you want to draw a border for each cell of the matrix, that's another topic. But also possible. Should they all be the same size, irregardless what's actually drawn in each cell?

Comment: It is actually possible to name `pic`s and refer to coordinates which are defined inside. For example, if you say `\tikzset{ my silly pic/.pic={ \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1) coordinate (-A); } }` and than you put `\pic (my first silly pic) at (0,0) {my silly pic};`, you can place a node at `(my first silly pic-A)`. I don't know whether this can help here, though.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I tried to clarify: I meant the usual rules in a matrix. Like, horizontal and vertical lines that separate the cells.

Comment: @Bubaya, maybe you should add `between origines` to the row and column separations to obtain a grid-compatible positioning? See ch. 20.3.2 in the manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm, something is strange with your code: wherever I try to add `[draw=black]` to show the outer shape of each `\pic`, which hopefully results in the grid you look for, it fails:

- no line is drawn
- perhaps it's hidden by the way you draw the pics

So, here's a fallback for you:

- draw a grid on it
- further tune and tweak its starting points etc. (still needed)
- change its color `\draw [draw=blue,ystep=12.3mm,  ...`
- if necessary clip the result to visually remove outer lines

Perhaps there's a way to obtain the dimensions of the final matrix to better set the grid parameters. I just used *trial & error* assuming x- and y-steps are constant.

[image: result][image: result in blue]

```
... 
        }; % end of matrix
       \draw [ystep=12.3mm, yshift=1mm, xstep=13mm, xshift=-1mm] (-3,-3) grid (3,3);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```